# How to adjust open or Save dialog display based on resolution?

Tags: c#

I have developed a window C# application it's working fine in normal DPI(96 dpi). My customer requested to run my application in 200 Dpi. While run my application in 200 Dpi everything is fine. But when i try to open one dialog it doesn't show  the full size.

[image]

In dialog open or save and cancel button showing. I searched in net but i can't get the exact solution. Can any body help me to solve this issue.

Thank is advance

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10131953/simple-way-to-make-openfiledialog-smaller-in-size

Comment: Presumably, the user has the same problem with every other application on their computer. Like if they open Notepad and then display the Open dialog, it should look identical. That would suggest it's not a bug with your program, it's simply that they have too small a monitor for their DPI setting.

Comment: @CodyGray: My 13" laptop screen has a resolution of 3200 x 1800 pixels and I obviously have a high DPI setting. Windows and Office dialogs look just fine but many third party windows and dialogs are very small and weird looking. I applaud a developer that tries to write applications that is usable also on modern hardware.

Comment: thanks to all of you for your comments. still now i didn't get the solution friends. Can any one tell how to resolve this.

Comment: As suggested in kostas's link, I suppose the size can be varied only through win32 api calls, and win forms might not have the facility to change thhe size. I hope you got the answer.